# What is use of Action<T>

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I read this below code which takes `Action<T> and returns Action<T>`

```
private static Action<HttpContext> WrapCallback(Action<HttpContextBase> callback)
{
        if (callback != null)
        {
            return delegate(HttpContext context)
            {
                callback(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
            }
            ;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

`What is the use of returning Action<T>` instead of the know types like object, string, etc. I dont understand how it can be used in programs. Any scenarios/example please

Comment: For a start, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function
and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function

Comment: `Action<T>` is a known type, just like object, string, etc.

Comment: MSDN is your friend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding a basic concept that is well explained in the product documentation.

Answer (score 2):

For you example you can do like this

call back function

```
public void ActFunction(int a)
         {
         }
```

code for calling

```
Action<int> act = new Action<int>(aActFunction);
WrapCallback(act);
```

---

Action instead  is function that you want to pass to the WrapCallback

it is function

```
public class ActionDemo
{
     public void ActFunction(int a)
     {
     }
     public void ActFunction1()
     {
     }

     static void Main()
     {
        ActionDemo ad = new ActionDemo();


        Action act1 = new Action(ad.ActFunction1);
        act1();     
        Action<int> act = new Action<int>(ad.ActFunction);
        act();
     }
}
```

more details about it avaible in this blog post : http://pranayamr.blogspot.no/2012/08/delegate-and-action-and-func-and-lamda.html

Comment: But I dont understand what the code does and why it is designed in the confused way. not understandable for me :(

Comment: @Billa you'd have to ask the person who wrote that code for the *why*.

Comment: The int parameter for `act1()` is missing

Comment: @Stijn, I dont know which  persom from Microsoft wrote [this code](http://dotnetinside.com/en/framework/v4.0.30319/System.Web/HttpContextWrapper)

Answer (score 2):

Basically, it's an equivalent to creating a lambda manually;

```
Action<HttpContext> callback1 = WrapCallback(DoSomething);
Action<HttpContext> callback2 = x => DoSomething(new HttpContextWrapper(x));
```

In other words, it wraps the function given as an argument inside another function and returns the new function.

The new function - when called - wraps the HttpContext parameter inside a HttpContextWrapper and calls the original function with it.